# Sideway Movement When Moving Cursor Horizontally Only

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

Trying to make a LUA script that gets a mouse position and then inputs key movement accordingly

If the mouse is moving towards the right, I want the character to move left and vice versa.

Found bunch of codes here online and tried stitching them but no consistent result

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
local distance_horiz  = 2  -- x, pixels
local distance_vert   = 2  -- x, pixels
local key_press_delay = 0  -- y, ms

local screen_width  = 2560   --  set your game screen resolution here
local screen_height = 1440

--------------------------------------------------------------------

local active
function OnEvent(event, arg)
 
     
  if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
   repeat 
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
      local horiz, vert, horiz_key, vert_key, horiz_key_tm, vert_key_tm = 0, 0
         local prev_MMB, prev_x, prev_y = true
         repeat
            Sleep(10)
            local MMB = IsMouseButtonPressed(2)
            local exit = MMB and not prev_MMB
            prev_MMB = MMB
            local x, y = GetMousePosition()
            x = math.floor((x + (0.5 + 2^-16)) * (screen_width-1) / (2^16-1))
            y = math.floor((y + (0.5 + 2^-16)) * (screen_height-1) / (2^16-1))
            x, y, prev_x, prev_y = x - (prev_x or x), y - (prev_y or y), x, y
            horiz, vert = horiz + x, vert + y
            local tm = GetRunningTime()
            -- horiz
            if tm >= (horiz_key_tm or 0) then
               if math.abs(horiz) >= distance_horiz then
                  local new_key
                  if horiz > 0 then
                     horiz, new_key = horiz - distance_horiz, "D"
                  else
                     horiz, new_key = horiz + distance_horiz, "A"
                  end
                  if new_key ~= horiz_key then
                     if horiz_key then
                        ReleaseKey(horiz_key)
                     end
                     PressKey(new_key)
                  end
                  horiz_key, horiz_key_tm = new_key, (horiz_key_tm or tm) + key_press_delay
               elseif horiz_key then
                  ReleaseKey(horiz_key)
                  horiz_key, horiz_key_tm = nil
               end
            end
     until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end    
   until not IsMouseButtonPressed(3)
end  



 
end
```

Comment: LGS/GHUB is unable to handle mouse movement (no event is generated when you move the mouse).  But it can read mouse coordinates inside another generated event (for example, inside mouse button click event).  This means you should click a button, move mouse horizontally, and finally either release the button or press (another or the same) button to stop the reading of the mouse coordinates.  Is it OK for you?

Comment: Yes This works I wanted it to work on my LMB

Answer (score 0):

To turn the script on press Middle Mouse Button.
To turn the script off press MMB again.
While the script is on, horizontal mouse movement is echoed by "A"/"D" keys

```
local distance_horiz = 20   -- each 20 pixels makes one key-press A/D
local screen_width = 2560   -- set your game screen resolution here
local active

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 3 then  -- MMB
        active = not active
        if active then
            local horiz, prev_x, exit, key = 0
            repeat
                Sleep(10)
                local MMB = IsMouseButtonPressed(2)
                exit, active = MMB and not active, MMB
                local x = GetMousePosition()
                x = math.floor((x + (0.5 + 2^-16)) * (screen_width-1) / (2^16-1))
                horiz, prev_x = horiz + x - (prev_x or x), x
                if math.abs(horiz) >= distance_horiz then
                    if horiz > 0 then
                        horiz, key = horiz - distance_horiz, "A"
                    else
                        horiz, key = horiz + distance_horiz, "D"
                    end
                    PressAndReleaseKey(key)
                end
            until exit
        end
    end
end
```